# How to avoid sudden stopped in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, events

In my access project, I have Navigation form named **DepartmentMgtWindow** and one of its subform is named **DepartmentPanel**. In my DepartmentPanel I also have subform/subreport that target a form named **PcnsList**, where PcnsList is a **continuous form**. Consider the image below:

[image]

In my event **(On Open)** for DepartmentMgtWindow, I want to hide PcnsList hence the code:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Form_PcnsList.Visible = False
End Sub
```

When I run the project, my access suddenly crashes and gets **Microsoft Access has stopped working**, and if I comment out the code inside the event it works fine.

I also put **On Open** event in my DepartmentPanel and I am getting the same result.

Any help/suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: `Form_PcnsList` doesn't sound right. You need to hide the control the inner subform resides, e.g. `Me.SubformControl.Visible = False`

Comment: @KostasK. I tried both: ```Me.Controls("PcnsList").Visible = False``` and ```Me.PcnsList.Visible = False``` but it does not hide the continuous form when open.

Comment: Add an OnError and catch the error., and then edit your question with the error message

Comment: What code sets the subform Visible = True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code fails because form PcnsList is not open as an independent object and therefore is not in active Forms collection.

Subform path referencing must be through container names, not form names.

Looks like PcnsList is on a form that is loaded as Navigation Target. Access assigns container that holds target forms a name of **NavigationSubform** by default. So if the embedded subform container control is named PcnsList and code is behind DepartmentMgtWindow form, try (yes, that is the word **Form**, do not replace with a form name):
`Me.NavigationSubform.Form.PcnsList.Visible`

I always give container control a name different from object it holds, like `ctrPCN`, then:
`Me.NavigationSubform.Form.ctrPCN.Visible`

For code behind DepartmentPanel: `Me.ctrPCN.Visible = True`

However, advise to set PcnsList subform container as not visible in its design and then code makes visible when needed. This would eliminate problem code from main form.

Comment: Thank you very much for your enlightenment. But I just want to know how should I reference the form when I am on Modules. When I am on VBA editor my forms shows like this ```Form_PcnsList```, ```Form_DepartmentPanel```, ```Form_DepartmentMgtWindow```, etc. I thought no problem if I directly calls it on my modules.

Comment: If code is in a general module replace `Me` with `Forms!DepartmentMgtWindow` or `Form_DepartmentMgtWindow`.